# Bash tcp redirection end of transmission

Tags: bash, shell-script, tcp, xinetd

I made a simple network service with xinetd which reads a string from tcp socket and outputs its encoded view. Original binary(qrencode) just reading stdin.

It works fine when I use it with `netcat` as `echo string | nc <ip> <port>`

But it doesn't answer when I try to use it via bash tcp redirection.

```
exec 7<>/dev/tcp/<ip>/<port>
echo string >&7
cat <&7
```

It waits forever. I tried echoing \004, cat /dev/null to this fd and no luck.
How can I make it working?

Answer (score 4):

That `inetd` service or yours is probably waiting for EOF before exiting (and then closing the connection).

To do that, you'd need the client to shutdown the sending side of the socket while still keeping the receive side open. That's what `nc` does when it detects EOF on its stdin.

The `/dev/tcp/host/port` virtual interface of `bash` (copied from ksh) doesn't allow that. Even `zsh`'s `ztcp` more flexible alternative doesn't have the ability to asymmetrically shutting down connections.

You could rely on a timeout instead, but that would be unreliable. So best  it to keep relying on dedicated utilities like `nc` or `socat` (possibly with a coproc to have  a similar interface), or use a programming language with a proper network API (with an interface to `shutdown()`).

The 0x04 character (`^D`) only means EOF for terminal devices when the line discipline is in `icanon` mode (implements a crude line editor). So for that to work you'd have to insert a pseudo-terminal in between the socket created by `xinetd` and your service. For instance, by starting it with:

```
socat - exec:'your-service',pty,raw,icanon,echo=0,discard=,lnext=,werase=,kill=,start=,stop=,rprnt=,erase=,fdout=3
```

instead of

```
your-service
```

Then you'd need to send:

```
printf 'text\n\4' >&7
```

Or:

```
printf 'text\4\4' >&7
```

for your-service to see the end of input.

Because of that line editor, `your-service` will only see input when you send newline or `^D` characters (we've disabled all the other editing characters like `werase`, `erase`, `kill` above and the `^C`, `^Z`... handling is also disabled as part of `raw`).

So you might as well insert an input pre-processor instead that quits upon that 0x4 character like:

```
awk -v RS='\4' -v ORS= '{print; exit}' | your-service
```

(note that that `awk` can't be `mawk` as `mawk` insists in not processing its input as long as it's not received a full buffer or eof).

Comment: Thahk you. I expected something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if your service is not closing the established TCP session, there is no other way than stopping the connection client-side. For example using the timeout command:

```
timeout 1 cat <&7
```

Also, the other commands (`echoing \004, cat /dev/null`) that you are trying most probably fail because you execute those from another shell. Note that the file descriptor 7 is attached to the shell where you executed the first `exec 7<>/dev/tcp/<ip>/<port>`, and so you can only interact with it from within the first shell.

[Reference](http://xmodulo.com/tcp-udp-socket-bash-shell.html)

Comment: I tried timeout but it wasn't help. It simply prints nothing.
I also tried 7>&- and then cat <&7, same thing.